Automatic Price Calculation
I'm trying to find a formula i can use which will automatically calculate a price based on certain day rate criteria.
My pricing structure is as follows:
0-5 days = £35 a day
6-10 days = £25 a day
11-15 days = £15 a day
So for up to 5 days the rate will be calculated at £35 a day, but if customer books 7 days for instance the rate will be calculated at £35 for 5 days and £25 for the remaining 2 days.
Hope that makes sense?
Is there any easy way to achieve this?
Thanks
Chris

You can use:
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(A5),A2:B4,2))

Where A5 is the number of days and A2:B4 is the following lookup table:



Number
Value




0
35


6
25


11
15




One more thing, if i wanted to calculate a 10% discount automatically on the total based on selecting yes or no in a separate column, is this achievable?

Assuming Yes/No is in B5, you can use:
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(A5),A2:B4,2))*IF(B5="Yes",0.9,1)
